# Unclear Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-shade-plugin, jar-signing

I have a "uber jar" created with the Maven shade plugin which includes:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-jar-dependencies</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MyDependencies</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.locationtech.geomesa</groupId>
          <artifactId>geomesa-spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.locationtech.geomesa</groupId>
          <artifactId>geomesa-spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.locationtech.geomesa</groupId>
          <artifactId>geomesa-spark-jts_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.locationtech.geomesa</groupId>
          <artifactId>geomesa-feature-all_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.locationtech.geomesa</groupId>
          <artifactId>geomesa-feature-kryo_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.locationtech.geomesa</groupId>
          <artifactId>geomesa-feature-avro_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.locationtech.geomesa</groupId>
          <artifactId>geomesa-feature-nio_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
            <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

However when I deploy it to AWS/GLUE ad dependency in the job I get:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:330)
....
```

From command line I have run:

```
$ jarsigner -verify target/my-jar-dependencies-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

jar is unsigned.
```

which returns as expected that the jar is unsigned. However this may be the cause of the above error. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at a list of which files are actually in your jar?

Comment: yes the files look ok, I can run the application using that jar locally

Comment: the fact is that excluding SF/DSA/RSA will remove any other certificate

Comment: I posted the full pom.xml